# How to use types provided by Supabase in my TypeScript project?

Tags: typescript, types, supabase

Ok so I'm new to TypeScript and the strict type checking is really getting on my nerve since I've been mainly writing python in the last couple of years. I'm working on a TypeScript project that makes queries to Supabase db.

Here's my code:

```
export type DriverPost =
  Database["public"]["Tables"]["driver_posts"]["Row"]
export type Profile = Database["public"]["Tables"]["profiles"]["Row"]
export type Location = Database["public"]["Tables"]["locations"]["Row"]

export type RequestResponse = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof fetchDriverPosts>>

export type DriverPostType = Array<
  DriverPost & {
    author: Profile;
    departure: Location;
    destination: Location;
  }
  >

export async function fetchDriverPosts(searchParams?: {
  departure?: string;
  destination?: string;
  date?: Date;
  seats?: number;
  sortBy?: "departure_day";
}): Promise<DriverPostType> {
  // const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser();
  let query = supabase.from("driver_posts").select(`
      id,
      date,
      author: profiles (full_name, avatar_url, phone_number),
      departure:locations!driver_posts_departure_id_fkey (location_name),
      destination:locations!driver_posts_destination_id_fkey (location_name),
      time,
      details,
      fee,
      seats
    `);

  
  const { data, error } = await query.returns<
    Array<
      DriverPostType & {
        author: Profile;
        departure: Location;
        destination: Location;
      }
    >
  >();

  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
  console.log("fetched data is", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error fetching driver posts: ", error);
    throw error;
  }

  return data;
```

The query I'm making joins a couple of tables and returns an object that references 3 tables. Supabase generates types for me for each table as I declared at the top of the file and I want to use these types in the function return type as well as in other files where the returned data is being used. For example I need a PostDetails type that kind of extends the DriverPost type with Profile and Location type provided by Supabase.

I tried using this syntax:

```
export type DriverPostType = Array<
  DriverPost & {
    author: Profile;
    departure: Location;
    destination: Location;
  }
  >
```

but I'm not sure what this is achieving.

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do is put the `Database` type in as the type for the Supabase `createClient` function.

Here's an example how to do that:

```
import Database from '@/lib/database.types.ts'; //replace with your import location
const supabase = createClient<Database>(process.env.SUPABASE_URL!, process.env.SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!);
```

This means that you can get intellisense for the tables you want to use, the types required for things like inserts, updates and also when selecting certain columns, letting you know if you misspelt it (by having the `data` property be null).

Secondly, I always setup a `global.types.ts` file for all projects where I specify out the types as well, just as you have done. For instance:

```
export type Profile = Database['public']['Tables']['profiles']['Row'];
```

This is so that my functions can look like this (which is super nice and helpful when updating types across the database):

```
import Database from '@/lib/database.types.ts'; //replace with your import location
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

export async function fetchProfile(id: string): Promise<Profile>
{
    const supabase = createClient<Database>(process.env.SUPABASE_URL!, process.env.SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!);
    const { data: profile, error } = await supabase.from('profiles').select('*').eq('id', id).single();

    if (error && !profile)
        return;
    else
        return profile;
}
```

Those types will also be carried over from the joins you're making from those other tables, you will just need to reference them based on their property name (in your case `const author = data.author;`).

Hopefully this helps and I hope you're enjoying Supabase.